# Very high ping and wifi drops since one week

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ping

On my Win10 computer, up-to-date, no virus / spywares, etc, from day to another one, I started having very high ping inconsistently, and WiFi drop. Sometimes Win10 tells me there is no internet connection. Other devices (smartphone, Mac, etc) doesn't have any problem. The router is OK (receiving 18mbps).

Then, I reinstalled my computer (total reset, Win10 reinstall, etc), still the same problem.
I changed my WiFi card to a USB WiFi dongle (waiting for a new WiFi PCIe card), 1 day without problem, and then, it happens again.

Every driver is up-to-date, I don't know where to seek..

Yesterday, in Valorant, I had 1100ms ping, unplayable, and this morning 9h, no problem, and 11h, big lag again ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you contacted your service provider?  A network driver wouldn’t cause the type of latency your experiencing

Comment: No, because on my mobile, I don't have this latency (playing TFT Mobile for example), should I ?

Comment: If you lower the frame rate, you still get the same problem?

Comment: Didn't tried, but what is the logic in there ?

Comment: @HeavyNounours - There isn’t any logic.  *Your frame rate does not have any effect on latency.*. You indicated you purchased a new WiFi adapter and had the same problem.  This is an indication the problem is the WiFi access point, which I will presume, is provided by your ISP.  What do you mean the issue doesn’t exist on “mobile”.  Additionally, I suspect the rolling behavior, is an indication of an ISP problem

Comment: Notwithstanding other device performance it sounds to me like interference from other WiFi networks or device radiating/transmitting in the band. What happens if you move the PC closer to the router?

Comment: Are TFT Mobile and Valorant being served from the same server?

Comment: @somebadhat Yes, when I play TFT on desktop (it's cross platform, same editor, Riot Games)

Comment: @davidgo Even closer, in the same room, same problem :/

I've ordered CPL plugs to pass through ethernet, but I want to understand what is the problem :/ 

I'll call my ISP !

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Had 1 USB WiFi that worked well for a week, after that time i started having high ping. I've changed that for another one (different manufacturer) that worked perfectly for a week more or less. Now it is inconsistent once more. Looks like you also play Valorant like me, maybe this game is causing some kind of problem?